# I literally can't understand the Independence Probability

Tags: probability-theory, independence

They say the coin flipping are independent events each other. (Gambler's fallacy).

And they also say that a set of probabilities is independent each other, if they satisfy P(A∩B) = P(B│A)×P(A) = P(A)×P(B).

But let's go back to the coin flipping for a second. There exists two elements in the S set, Head and Tail, and the probability of flipping Head, P(H), has only 1 element, H, so that P(H) = 1/2, which means H out of H and T.

Here, flipping a coin once again should be independent to the first one. But if they really are independent each other, it should satisfy P(H∩H) = P(H│H)×P(H) = P(H)×P(H) = 1/4, which is wrong, because P(H∩H) = P(H) = 1/2. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you may be confusing yourself by using the symbol $H$ to mean both a head on the first toss and a head on the second toss.  Try using $H_1$ and $H_2$.  Then $\Pr(H_1\cap H_2)=\frac14$.  Does this help?

Comment: Your events are not clear.  What does the event $H$ refer to?  You need to distinguish between the first toss coming up Heads and the second toss coming up Heads, those are the independent events.

Comment: So this is an issue with sloppy labelling. When you try to write out the meaning in English, your error becomes obvious. When you write $P(H\cap H)$, do you mean the probability of some random variable taking on the value $H$ and also the value $H$? Or do you mean two separate random variables both taking on the value $H$? You are confusing the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $P(H \cap H)$ you really mean $P(H_1 \cap H_2)$ with $H_1$ indicating that the first toss is heads, and $H_2$ indicating that the second toss is heads. In this case, indeed, $P(H_1 \cap H_2) = 1/2*1/2 = 1/4$

[image]

Comment: This is why I prefer the notation $P(X_1,X_2=H)$ for novices, where $X_1,X_2$ are coin-flipping RVs.

Comment: Thanks. But if there exist H1 and H2, how do you draw the whole set? Does S still have only two elements, H and T? And what about the subsets of them? Does there exist a countless subsets that have only H as their elements? Or there is just one subset for P(H) and you just use it like P(H1) P(H2) P(H3) depending on how you approach the problem?

Comment: Some possible events in the set would be (H1 & H2), (H1 & T2), (T1 & H2), (T1 & T2) each with probability 1/4. Or you could just have the events H1, H2, T1, T2 by themselves each with probability 1/2. Or you could construct an event (H1 or H2) which would have probability 3/4. I added a picture that might help

Comment: So you mean the whole set, S, keeps growing(?) in its amount of elements whenever you add an event?

Comment: The whole set S is of a finite fixed size, containing every possible event. What you're asking is essentially construction of a sigma-algebra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra

Comment: We need to be careful when we're talking about what S means. Here, I'm assuming you're referring to every possible event. Each event is a subset of all the possible outcomes. An outcome refers to the outcome of the full experiment. There are only 4 outcomes here (HH,HT,TH,TT) but there are many many events (choose any subset of the outcomes and you make an event).